# walk a dog vs walk a person

Tags: meaning

Does it have the same general meaning? Or does it have a completely different meaning somehow?

> He walked his grandfather to the house.
>
> He walked his dog to the park.

Answer (score 2):

To "walk a dog" means to put the dog on a leash, and walk somewhere with the dog. The purposes can be many, such as taking the dog somewhere for dog-oriented recreation, or to allow the dog to perform "bodily functions."

In the case of the grandfather, it means he walked beside his grandfather. Possibly just because he wanted to spend this time with his grandfather. Or possibly he was helping his grandfather because his grandfather is old. Or possibly being respectful, not wanting to let his grandfather walk home alone.

Comment: In Britain, when I was a teenager, a polite boy would _walk his girl home_ after a date.